How to Replace the Notification Bell Icon in Windows 11 Taskbar using Windhawk?
This is my first post on StackOverflow, and I apologize if I make any mistakes, especially since my English is not perfect. I’ve been trying to use the Windows 11 Taskbar Styler via the Windhawk program to customize some elements of my taskbar. Specifically, I want to replace the notification bell icon in the bottom-right corner with a custom image.
Although I successfully replaced the Windows Start button icon using the code below, I couldn’t find a working solution to replace the notification bell icon. The only thing I managed was hiding it, but I want to swap it with a new image. Actually I did the image replacement but I have a problem like double images. I don't understand exactly how to solve it, maybe I'm adding the image in the wrong way.
This is what my taskbar looks like now
I’ve tried a few things by using Inspect.exe, Resource Hacker, and Ghidra tools with some help from ChatGPT, but unfortunately, I couldn't achieve the desired result. If I narrow the visibility of the notification bell instead of setting its opacity to 0
, then the image is compressed. When I wanted to expand the narrowed winter, I couldn't adjust the width setting, so I made the opacity 0 so that it just became invisible and a space was opened for the image I wanted to put. I can also use the other method if you have an idea how to expand it. Here is the code I currently use for my taskbar styling:
This code hides the windows start button:
Target: Taskbar.ExperienceToggleButton#LaunchListButton[AutomationProperties.AutomationId=StartButton] > Taskbar.TaskListButtonPanel > Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.AnimatedVisualPlayer#Icon

Style: Visibility=Collapsed

This code allows me to replace the windows start button with a .webp file:
Target: Taskbar.ExperienceToggleButton#LaunchListButton[AutomationProperties.AutomationId=StartButton] > Taskbar.TaskListButtonPanel > Border#BackgroundElement

Style: Background:=<ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="https://emoji.discadia.com/emojis/resized/21451c25-da13-4697-b9d7-c2c97bf3bb49_48x48.webp" />

This code hides the notification bell:
Target: SystemTray.OmniButton#NotificationCenterButton > Grid > ContentPresenter > ItemsPresenter > StackPanel > ContentPresenter > SystemTray.IconView#SystemTrayIcon > Grid > Grid > SystemTray.TextIconContent
Style: Opacity=0

Here is another attempt to set a background image for the icon, but it didn’t work as expected:
Target: SystemTray.OmniButton#NotificationCenterButton > Grid > ContentPresenter > ItemsPresenter > StackPanel > ContentPresenter > SystemTray.IconView#SystemTrayIcon > Grid
Style: Background:=<ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="https://emoji.discadia.com/emojis/resized/810e480b-0308-43db-a1af-3a2d96cba4b4_48x48.webp" />

Has anyone successfully replaced the notification bell icon using Windhawk or a similar method? Am I missing some steps or is there another way to achieve this customization? I’d appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction! Also, it would be great if you can tell me exactly how to change other icons or show me the source.
